# Assuring i18n tag is not missed in html tags

Tags: html, angular, internationalization

We are building an angular 6 app and would like to implement I18n by angular. This requires us to include "i18n" in html tags containing translatable information. Is there any way to automate this and how can we test whether "i18n" is missing anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [angular-tslint-rules][1].

To check if i18n is missing, add this rule to your `tslint.json`:

```
"i18n": [
  true,
  "check-id",
  "check-text"
]
```

And execute the linter with `ng lint`.
Output should be:

```
ERROR: component.html[2, 8]: Each element containing text node should have an i18n attribute
```

Comment: This requires the unmaintaned package `angular-tslint-rules`.